# the idea of objects as, could come to be

Tags: meaning-in-context

Moreover, as museums and universities drew further apart toward the end of the nineteenth century, and as ***the idea of objects as a privileged route to knowing the world*** went into decline, collecting began to lose its status as a worthy intellectual pursuit, especially in the sciences. The really interesting and important aspects of science were increasingly those invisible to the naked eye, and the classification of things collected no longer promised to produce cutting-edge knowledge (Conn 1998). The term “butterfly collecting” ***could come to be*** used with the adjective “mere” to indicate a pursuit of secondary academic status.

[Reference](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qWEXz0Ns5sYJ:https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.729.3672%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf+&cd=2&hl=ko&ct=clnk&gl=kr)

---

1. I'd like to know if "***the idea of objects as a privileged route to knowing the world went into decline***" means "thinking objects as a privileged route to knowing the world."
2. I'd like to know if "***could come to be***" means "was able to become"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. is saying: that the notion that people in privileged positions could learn about history and culture by accumulating artefacts went out of fashion.
2. is saying that as a result of changing attitudes, people were able to talk about "butterfly collecting" as a pursuit having only secondary importance in academic circles.

It is not clear to me whether the phrase "butterfly collecting" is to be taken literally or is a metaphor for collecting trivial artefacts.